# MatLab ODE start/stop conditions for ode15i

Tags: matlab, ode

I was searching for ways to terminate MATLAB ode when it meets a particular condition. I found the answer in this topic  [MatLab ODE start/stop conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768447/matlab-ode-start-stop-conditions?newreg=0ac2f9a922b54ce18a985f148c697dd5), where the use of 'events' was discussed. However this applies to ode45 and when I attempted to use 'events' with ode15i, it simply didn't worked and MATLAB is showing error.

I am trying to learn this with simple example and solved a simple system of differential equations as given below.

dx/dt = 5x + 3y; dy/dt = x + 7y; I solved them using ode45 and tried to do the same with ode15i, but it doesn't work. Given below are my codes.

**With ode45**

```
    function start_stop_test_ode45
    y0 = [5;1];
    tv = linspace(0,2,100);
    options = odeset('Events',@events);    
    f = @(t,y) [5*y(1) + 3*y(2);y(1) + 7*y(2)];
    [t,Y] = ode45(f,tv,y0,options);
    xNI = Y(:,1);
    yNI = Y(:,2);
    xCF   =  3*exp(4*t) + 2*exp(8*t);
    yCF   = -1*exp(4*t) + 2*exp(8*t);
    % Here we plot all the graphs
    figure(1)
    plot(t,xNI,'--k',t,xCF,'r','Linewidth',1.75)
    xlabel('t (s)')
    ylabel('x')
    legend('Numerical Solution','Closed Form Solution')
    figure(2)
    plot(t,yNI,'--k',t,yCF,'r','Linewidth',1.75)
    xlabel('t (s)')
    ylabel('y')
    legend('Numerical SOlution','Closed Form Solution')
    % Here we solve plot the variation of x with y
    figure(3)
    plot(xNI,yNI,'k','Linewidth',2);
    end

    function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y)
    value = [y(1) - 7782;y(2) - 8863];  % Detect y = 7356
    isterminal = [1;1];
    direction = [0;0];
    end
```

**With ode15i**

```
    function start_stop_test_ode15i
    clc;clear all
    t0 = 0;
    y0 = [5;1];
    Fxdy0 = [1;1];
    Fxdyp0 = [0;0];
    yp0 = [28;12];
    tRange = [0 2];
    options = odeset('Events',@events);
    [y0,yp0] = decic(@ode15ifun,t0,y0,Fxdy0,yp0,Fxdyp0);
    sol = ode15i(@ode15ifun,tRange,y0,yp0,options);
    tv = linspace(0,2,100);
    sv = deval(sol,tv);
    sv = sv';
    t = tv;
    xNI = sv(:,1);
    yNI = sv(:,2);
    xCF   =  3*exp(4*t) + 2*exp(8*t);
    yCF   = -1*exp(4*t) + 2*exp(8*t);
    % Here we plot all the graphs
    figure(4)
    plot(t,xNI,'--k',t,xCF,'r','Linewidth',1.75)
    xlabel('t (s)')
    ylabel('x')
    legend('Numerical Solution','Closed Form Solution')
    figure(5)
    plot(t,yNI,'--k',t,yCF,'r','Linewidth',1.75)
    xlabel('t (s)')
    ylabel('y')
    legend('Numerical SOlution','Closed Form Solution')
    % Here we solve plot the variation of x with y
    figure(6)
    plot(xNI,yNI,'k','Linewidth',2);
    end

    function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y)
    value = [y(1) - 7782;y(2) - 8863];  % Detect y = 7356
    isterminal = [1;1];
    direction = [0;0];
    end
```

Where the ode15ifun is

```
    function res = ode15ifun(t,y,yp)
    %UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
        res1 = yp(1) - 5*y(1)- 3*y(2);
        res2 = yp(2) - y(1) - 7*y(2);
        res  = [res1;res2];
    end
```

ode45 is working fine but while using ode15i I am getting error message. Can anyone help as to how to do the same with ode15i?

Thank you very much

(In Response to TroyHaskin) I am adding an image file of the error message for your reference. 
[image]

Comment: If the error is "Too many input arguments", that's because `ode15i` requires the event function signature `[value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y,yp)` with the addition of `yp` as an argument since that is also an unknown for the fully implicit solver.  **Also, could you post the error, please?**

Comment: @TroyHaskin Hi TroyHaskin, Thank you very much for your help. You are right, the error message shows "Too many input arguments". My mistake was that in the events command I was writing events(t,y) instead of  events(t,y,yp). Now it is working fine. I added an image file of the error message that I was getting to the main body where I posted my doubt (for your reference).  Thank once again for your help Troy...Thank you very much..

Comment: If you have a good answer, why don't you answer your own question?